# Deploy Express server and test GraphQL API via CircleCI

Tags: node.js, express, continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-2.0

I wish to test that my Express server launches properly and that my endpoint retrieves the correct information. I wish to do this in CI so that I can monitor when my application is no longer working, if I make any changes in the future.

It's a very simple application, my server looks like this:

**`server.js`**

```
import express from 'express';
import graphqlHTTP from 'express-graphql';
import { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString, GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';
import cors from 'cors';

const QueryRoot = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: () => ({
        hello: {
            type: GraphQLString,
            resolve: () => "Hello world!"
        }
    })
});

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({ query: QueryRoot });

const app = express();

app.use(cors()); // enable cors

app.use('/api', graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true,
}));

app.listen(1337, () => {
    console.log('Server running on port: 1337');
});
```

**`basicTest.test.js`**:

```
const chai = require('chai');

const expect = chai.expect;
const url = `http://localhost:1337`;
const request = require('supertest')(url);

describe('GraphQL', () => {
    it('Response returns hello world', (done) => {
        request.post('/api')
            .send({ query: ' { hello }' })
            .expect(200)
            .end((err, res) => {
                if (err) return done(err);
                expect(res.body.data.hello).to.contain('Hello world!');
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

My `.circleci/config.yml` looks like this:

```
# Javascript Node CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-javascript/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/node:10.16.0

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/mongo:3.4.4

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      - checkout

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
            - v1-dependencies-

      - run: npm install

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}

      - run: 
          npm start &
          npm test
```

and **`package.json`**:

```
{
    "name": "graphql-express-server",
    "repository": {
        "url": "myURL"
    },
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon -r esm server.js",
        "test": "mocha test/*.test.js"
    },
    "author": "AuthorName",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "esm": "^3.2.25",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-graphql": "^0.9.0",
        "graphql": "^14.4.2",
        "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
        "supertest": "^4.0.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "chai": "^4.2.0",
        "mocha": "^6.2.0"
    }
}
```

I tried adding `&` to the end of my `npm start` command but that just skips the entire process as far as I can see. The issue I'm getting is `'Error: ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused'` when the test gets executed.

Do I need to host the server elsewhere? I'm unsure what I'm supposed to do. I've never really tested the back end in CI before.

***EDIT:***

My commands are as follows:

```
- run: 
    npm start &
- run:
    sleep 5
- run: 
    npm test
```

And my output in CI is as follows:

```
--------------------------------
***npm start &***

#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
npm start &

--------------------------------
***sleep 5***

#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
sleep 5

--------------------------------
***npm test***

#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
npm test

> graphql-express-server@1.0.0 test /home/circleci/repo
> mocha test/*.test.js



  GraphQL
    1) Response returns hello world


  0 passing (14ms)
  1 failing

  1) GraphQL
       Response returns hello world:
     Error: ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused
      at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:165:15)
      at localAssert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:131:12)
      at /home/circleci/repo/node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:128:5
      at Test.Request.callback (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:728:3)
      at ClientRequest.req.once.err (node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:647:10)
      at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
      at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
      at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)



npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
Exited with code 1

--------------------------------
```

As you can see, the message `Server running on port: 1337` does not show up in my `npm start &` step console section.

Any suggestions? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm start &` won't wait for server to start, are you sure your server is listening on the port by the time your test makes a request? I.e. do you have `'Server running on port: 1337'` in your console on CI? If not then try running `sleep 3` before starting tests

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I have the command `npm start`, followed by `npm test` then it just hangs on the `Server running on port: 1337` message and does not execute my tests. Any suggestions?

Comment: Using `npm start &` is correct since otherwise it will wait until the process finishes (and it won't of course). My suggestion was to use `sleep 3` command between `npm start &` and `npm test` so that your server is listening by the time you start your tests.

Comment: Try combining `npm start & sleep 5` in one command, perhaps you can't see logs of the prev command if the next one is already started. Also, try increasing `sleep` to 30s to be sure your server is running